# Count number of days dynamically in php

Tags: php, strtotime

```
$date = $_POST['date']; - dynamic date
$vd = $_POST['visitdays']; - dynamic days
$date = strtotime($date);
$date =date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+".$vd, $date));
```

Above code count number of days dynamically in PHP.
It works fine on my localhost, but not working on my cpanel.
Cpanel works static code.

Comment: What do you mean it works static code? Perhaps you are caching the page so it doesn't refresh / execute properly?

Comment: print value of $_POST['date'] and $_POST['visitdays'] to see what it has. In case it is working with static value then there is chance of variable not set or have garbage value in $_POST.

Comment: $_POST['date']- Jul-22-2015 $_POST['visitdays'] -21 days Both values changed dynamic. that correct. I'm Confused below line bold & italic words. $date =date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+".$vd, $date)); its work properly on localhost in cpanel i got 01-01-1970 this date.

Comment: Hello Epodax ya statically it works good. i need dynamically days change.  $date =date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+".$vd, $date)); . this code $vd is dynamically changed number of days and count

Comment: maytham@ PHP Version 5.4.40